# Issue creating/accessing hive external table with s3 location from spark thrift service

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have configured the **s3 keys** (access key and secret key) in a **jceks** file using **hadoop-credential** api. Commands used for the same are as below:

*hadoop credential create fs.s3a.access.key -provider jceks://hdfs@nn_hostname/tmp/s3creds_test.jceks*

*hadoop credential create fs.s3a.secret.key -provider jceks://hdfs@nn_hostname/tmp/s3creds_test.jceks*

Then, I am opening a connection to **Spark Thrift Server** using beeline and passing the jceks file path in the connection string as below:

*beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://hostname:10001/;principal=hive/_HOST@?hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs@nn_hostname/tmp/s3creds_test.jceks;*

Now, when I try to create an external table with the location in s3, it fails with the below exception:

*CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table_on_s3 (col1 String, col2 String) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' LOCATION 's3a://bucket_name/kalmesh/';*

**Exception:** Error: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException s3a://bucket_name/kalmesh: getFileStatus on s3a://bucket_name/kalmesh: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: request_id), S3 Extended Request ID: extended_request_id=) (state=,code=0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jceks support for the fs.s3a. secrets went in until Hadoop 2.8. I don't *think*; it's hard to tell from the source. If that is the case, and you are using Hadoop 2.7, then the secret isn't going to to be picked up. Afraid you will have to put it in the config.

Comment: I am using **HDP 2.5** which has **Hadoop 2.7** and **spark 1.6**. Same approach works perfectly for **Hive Thrift Server**

Comment: Afraid the JCEKS support is in Hadoop 2.8 and HDP2.6, not 2.5. You are going to have to go inline, I'm afraid. In EC2 it'd be picked up automatically, otherwise, you can do it in the AWS environment variables on the worker nodes

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, just with Drill instead of Hive. But like in your case:

- using Hadoop 2.9 jars (1st version to support AWS KMS)
- writing to s3a://
- encrypting with SSE-KMS

... and got **AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied**.

In my case (perhaps in yours, as well) the exception description was a bit ambiguous. The reported **AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied** did not originate from **S3** but from **KMS**! Access was denied to the key I used for encryption. User making the API calls was not on key's users list - once I added that user to key's list writing started to work and I could create encrypted tables on s3a://...

Answer (score 0):

For me the following `s3` permissions were required:

```
s3:ListBucket
s3:GetObject
s3:PutObject
```

I was receiving the same error and was missing `s3:ListBucket`.

As for KMS permissions (if applicable):

```
kms:Decrypt
kms:Encrypt
kms:GenerateDataKey
```